# failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, grails, jackson

I have a function that indexes a pretty big object into ElasticSearch.

```
void indexProject(Project project, User user) {
        PublicProject publicProject = projectService.toPublic(project, user)
        elasticSearchClientProviderService.getClient().index { IndexRequest.Builder<PublicProject> it ->
            it.index(ProjectsIndex)
            it.id(project.id.toString())
            it.document(publicProject)
        }
    }
```

Where `PublicProject` is somewhat complex:

```
class PublicProject {
    Long id
    String title
    String description
    String solution
    String currentSituation
    String disadvantages
    String problemStatement
    String successCriteria
    Long workspaceId

    ProjectStatus status
    Date dateCreated

    PublicTool[] tools
    PublicProjectAssignee[] assignees
}
```

And the main complexity is coming from the list of tools `PublicTool[] tools`. There are 10 different potential tools and they all inherit from `PublicTool` class.

```
package priz.api.shared.tools

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo
import priz.api.tools.ToolType
import priz.api.tools.ToolUtilizationStatus

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes([
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicFortyPrinciplesTool.class, name = "TOOL_40_PRINCIPLES"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicRrmTool.class, name = "RRM"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicUimTool.class, name = "UIM"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicCecTool.class, name = "CEC"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicCecTool.class, name = "APA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicEbsTool.class, name = "EBS"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicNineWindowsTool.class, name = "NINE_WINDOWS"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicFiveWhysTool.class, name = "FIVE_WHYS"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicPerceptionMapTool.class, name = "P_MAP"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PublicSfmTool.class, name = "SFM")
])
abstract class PublicTool {

    Long id
    ToolType type
    String title
    ToolUtilizationStatus status
    Integer revision

    Date dateCreated
}
```

Before we added all the type mapping annotations the indexing worked perfectly well. However, without them, the deserialization didn't work. Once added, the deserialization works as expected, but when I am trying to index the object, I am now getting the following error:

```
[es/index] failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:121)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:136)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/index] failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:278)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:144)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:953)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.index(ElasticsearchClient.java:970)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at search.ProjectSearchService.indexProject(ProjectSearchService.groovy:40)
    at priz.api.project.ProjectService.$pub__updateOpen(ProjectService.groovy:234)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at priz.api.project.ProjectController$_updateOpen_closure10$_closure22$_closure23.doCall(ProjectController.groovy:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at priz.api.controller.BaseController$Trait$Helper.withExceptionsHandling(BaseController.groovy:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at priz.api.project.ProjectController$_updateOpen_closure10$_closure22.doCall(ProjectController.groovy:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at priz.api.controller.BaseController$Trait$Helper.withValidatedCommand(BaseController.groovy:91)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at priz.api.project.ProjectController$_updateOpen_closure10.doCall(ProjectController.groovy:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at priz.api.security.PermissionsAwareController$Trait$Helper.canUpdateProject(PermissionsAwareController.groovy:38)
    at priz.api.project.ProjectController.updateOpen(ProjectController.groovy:118)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

I suspect it is something really dumb, but could not find the reason for it. And the error is not very descriptive.

**UPDATE**

I continued digging into it, and not it is clear to be that the ES is the one that returned 400 error.

I am having difficulties to debug and understand what the annotations change that result in a failure of ExlasticSearch to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this one. The problem was that this annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
```

means that a property will be added to an object called `type`. However, there is one already, and as a result, this property will be duplicated, which creates an invalid json.

The solution for it (at least the one I found), it to define a different property in annotation:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "toolType")
```

This will create an additional property `toolType` in json, but it will; be removed in deserialization.